# Oracle scheduler max_jobs_Slave_processes is set to null, how many will be allocated?

Tags: oracle, parallelism, jobs

Executing the following query against my database:

```
select value 
from dba_scheduler_global_attribute
where attribute_name='MAX_JOB_SLAVE_PROCESSES';
```

yields a value of `NULL`.  My question is what is the maximum number of slave processes that could be allocated, for job runs, when this value is set to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` implies no limits. Anything other than `NULL` sets a limit.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin001.htm#i1006314).